# Parse a Generated File Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse generated files into a list of objects.

Unfortunately the structure of the generated files is not always the same, but they contain the same fields (and lots of other garbage).

For example:

```
    function foo();              # Don't Care
    function maybeanotherfoo();  # Don't Care
    int maybemoregarbage;        # Don't Care

    
    product_serial = "CDE1102"; # I want this <---------------------
    unnecessary_info1 = 10;     # Don't Care
    unnecessary_info2 = "red"   # Don't Care
    product_id = 1134412;       # I want this <---------------------
    unnecessary_info3 = "88"    # Don't Care

    product_serial = "DD1232";  # I want this <---------------------
    product_id = 3345111;       # I want this <---------------------
    unnecessary_info1 = "22"    # Don't Care
    unnecessary_info2 = "panda" # Don't Care

    product_serial = "CDE1102"; # I want this <---------------------
    unnecessary_info1 = 10;     # Don't Care
    unnecessary_info2 = "red"   # Don't Care
    unnecessary_info3 = "bear"  # Don't Care
    unnecessary_info4 = 119     # Don't Care
    product_id = 1112331;       # I want this <---------------------
    unnecessary_info5 = "jj"    # Don't Care
```

I want a list of objects (each object has: serial and id).

I have tried the following:

```
import re

class Product:
    def __init__(self, id, serial):
        self.product_id = id
        self.product_serial = serial

linenum = 0
first_string = "product_serial"
second_string = "product_id"
with open('products.txt', "r") as products_file:
    for line in products_file:
        linenum += 1
        if line.find(first_string) != -1:
            product_serial = re.search('\"([^"]+)', line).group(1)
            #How do I proceed?
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: So what does your code do? Does it work? Are there errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: My code can find the first product_serial (CDE1102).  But how can I then find the product_id and then continue parsing from that point on?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
"Any advice" is far too broad for Stack Overflow.  There are many tutorials that show you how to read a file, how to process string data, etc.  You should be able to identify a constant string in the input and to separate input lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've inlined the data here using an `io.StringIO()`, but you can substitute `data` for your `products_file`.

The idea is that we gather key/values into `current_object`, and as soon as we have all the data we know we need for a single object (the two keys), we push it onto a list of `objects` and prime a new `current_object`.

You could use something like `if line.startswith('product_serial')` instead of the admittedly complex regexp.

```
import io
import re

data = io.StringIO("""
    function foo();             
    function maybeanotherfoo(); 
    int maybemoregarbage;       

    
    product_serial = "CDE1102"; 
    unnecessary_info1 = 10;     
    unnecessary_info2 = "red"   
    product_id = 1134412;       
    unnecessary_info3 = "88"    

    product_serial = "DD1232";  
    product_id = 3345111;       
    unnecessary_info1 = "22"    
    unnecessary_info2 = "panda" 

    product_serial = "CDE1102"; 
    unnecessary_info1 = 10;     
    unnecessary_info2 = "red"   
    unnecessary_info3 = "bear"  
    unnecessary_info4 = 119     
    product_id = 1112331;       
    unnecessary_info5 = "jj"    
""")

objects = []

current_object = {}
for line in data:
    line = line.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
    m = re.match(r'^(product_id|product_serial)\s*=\s*(\d+|"(?:.+?)");?$', line)

    if m:
        key, value = m.groups()
        current_object[key] = value.strip('"')
        if len(current_object) == 2:  # Got the two keys we want, ship the object
            objects.append(current_object)
            current_object = {}

print(objects)
```